# AWS API Gateway gives 'More than one client certificate passed' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, client-certificates, aws-api-gateway

I have set up Mutual TLS authentication for my API Gateway.
I then placed my client certificate in the truststore. The file contains the client certificate, intermediate and root certificates (private CA).

When accessing the API Gateway with a browser (Chrome on Windows), browser asks me to provide client certificate. I select the same certificate as I have placed in the trust store.

API Gateway reports the following in the browser:

{"message":"Invalid client certificate chain. More than one client certificate passed"}

UPDATE: I have also tried placing only intermediate and root certs in the trust store. Same error.

UPDATE 2: The same error is also reported when accessing the API with C# code (WebClient) loading the cert from Windows cert store or from disc (pfx file).

Answer (score 1):

If your trust store doesn't contain all the intermediate CA certs, then the client has to send a multi-cert chain.  The TLS handshake will work fine, but somewhere there is an explicit check that disallows multi-cert chains.  The status code is 400, not 403(!), and you get the "More than one client certificate passed" error.

However, if you're willing to put all the intermediate CA in the API gateway trust store, then the server should *not* ask the client to send intermediate certs.  The client should only send one cert in this case, and API gateway should work.

So something is going wrong when API gateway matches the initial client cert against the trust store, and it's not finding the intermediate.  I would check these things:

1. Make sure you use a specific version ID with the S3 link to the trust store.  Otherwise it's hard to tell which version it's actually using, because the API gateway will *not* automatically pick up a new version as soon as you add one to S3.  Maybe you're not using the trust store you think you are.
2. Your trust store should only include CA certs -- the root cert and intermediates.  You said you put the client cert in there, so maybe that's causing an issue.  Try taking it out.

Comment: I have now also tried only putting intermediate and root CA certs (two in total) in the trust store (concatenated as one file). I get the same error.

All the trust store pem files have had different names.

Comment: It's not clear whether it's complaining about the client sending too many certs or too many certs in the trust store.

Comment: I've only seen this message when the client sends multiple certs.  I could make it go away or come back in my deployment by adding or removing the intermediate cert in the trust store.

Comment: It's valid for the client to send multiple certs if it decides that it's necessary.  Depending on which browser you're using, you might be able to find some info about how it specifically makes that decision.  The servers sends its ca root CNs, and the client should stop when it chains to one of those... but maybe it's doing something more complicated.

Comment: Looks like this happens with certs created from the intermediate root. But only from PFX files using .NET or Windows browsers. Seems like a bug in AWS end.